# How to link to the next page if a Firebase login is successful?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm having some issues using Firebase Auth in a web application. I've used it before in mobile development, but can't get the hang of it with JavaScript web.

Here is my code:

```js
function signIn(){
    var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_").value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById("password_").value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        window.alert(errorCode);
    });
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        window.location("home.html");
    } else {}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDp_LRGOFoqZuvRTWmDLdheLy184QKMOFA",
    authDomain: "norednovember.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://norednovember.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "norednovember",
    storageBucket: "norednovember.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "569257202876"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <p id="email">Email</p>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email_"/>
    <p id="password">Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password_"/>
    <button id="signup" onclick="signIn()">Log In</button>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, what happens, is that when I enter an incorrect email or password, a window alert will pop up to let me know. But when I click "Ok" on the alert, it just automatically redirects me to the next page ("home.html").

How can I change it so that it will only redirect a user after a SUCCESSFUL login?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong with this, but could you not check to see if the error is the error exists, and if not then login?

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
     if (error) {

     }
     else{
        //login
     }
   });
```

I believe the correct way to do this would be to do the following.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    //user exists and is logged in
    //redirect Home
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // redirect to login
  }
});
```

If you make the above check on every single page, but do not have any redirects in the `true` condition, your site will basically be password "protected". Any time a user who is not logged in (or authenticated) attempts to access a page, it'll redirect them to the login until they are. I use "protected" because I don't know if that's the correct way to password protect a site, but it works on the frontend. If they are authenticated, then nothing changes and they are able to see the site - you'd also be able to safely call any `user` variables without it being `null`.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Even if the user is returned with an error and is rerouted to home.html, he/she is not redirected to "login", as per your code.

Comment: @caroline: the approach suggested by Torewin is the correct way of handling this. If you're having trouble implementing it, please update your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: I didn’t know if the first would work, I was trying to keep your code logic. The second one works, I have confirmed.